# Can I add a header/title row above the column labels of a pandas dataframe and output it to HTML?

Tags: python, html, pandas

as per the example below i am outputing a dataframe to the body of an email. Is it possible to add a header or title row above the column-labels row? Preferably a row that is one cell, the length of the dataframe, containing a string?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

styles = [{'props':[("font-family", "Calibri")]}, {
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [
           ('background-color', 'yellow')]}]
s = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)

html = s.hide_index().render()
with open("html_c.html","w") as fp:
   fp.write(html)
#to display in a jupyter notebook
display(HTML(html))
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=3)

### >>> begin
columns = list("ABCD")
columns = list(zip(['HEADER'] * 4, columns))             
#[('HEADER', 'A'), ('HEADER', 'B'), ('HEADER', 'C'), ('HEADER', 'D')]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(columns, names=['first', 'second'])    
### >>> end

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4),index=dates,columns=columns) # <--- also here
styles = [{'props':[("font-family", "Calibri")]}, {
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [
           ('background-color', 'yellow'),
           ('text-align','center')] # for alignment
        }]
s = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)

html = s.hide_index().render()
with open("html_c.html","w") as fp:
   fp.write(html)
#to display in a jupyter notebook
display(HTML(html))
```

[image]

Comment: follow-up question: it looks perfect in Jupyter, but when i export to the body of an email, only the first level of the index has a background color, the 2nd level has no background color. I am using win32 to send the email:

```
#send email with html in body
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = #email address
mail.Subject = "HTML TEST"
mail.HTMLBody = html
mail.Send()
```

Comment: Hmm this is kinda tricky since its not a problem from Pandas.Dataframe side anymore, you might need to post another question